# GCD serial (FIFO) queue, NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest (or NSData dataWithContentsOfURL) and memory management

Tags: networking, memory-management, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I have a table, with N rows. Each row is connected with a file to download so I need to do a serial queue of audio files to download. Each row must display a small icon to show if that file is downloading or in the waiting line. When the audio file is fully downloaded, I update the UI with NSNotifications and I simply pass to download the next in line.
Soo far I come up with this one, and it works fine.

```
swpadq.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.audioDownload", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

dispatch_async(_queue, ^{
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest_ = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:audioURL_
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                             timeoutInterval:60.0f];

    NSError *error_;

    NSLog(@"downloading %@", [audioURL_ absoluteString]);

    NSData *data_ = nil;

    data_ = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL_
                                  options:NSDataReadingUncached
                                    error:&error_];

    /*data_ =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest_
     returningResponse:nil
                                              error:&error_];*/

    });
```

The only "small" problem is that memory is growing, keeping the cache until all the files are fully downloaded and ONLY at this moment, the memory is freed. I have hundreds of files to download and this is a problem. How can I solve this?

And also, how can I release or nullify (I'm using ARC) the cache in order remove the strong retain cycle that the serial block is holding on each nsurlrequest? I truly don't understand what GCD does, when the queue is completed in order to freed all the objects (especially the url cache).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you need a **serial** queue? Must the downloads complete one after the other in a particular order? If not, then try using a concurrent queue. You can obtain the global concurrent queue as follows:

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);